# How do i chek if a given directory name exists or not in a parent directory bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

i'm trying to write s script that is checking if a given directory exists in a parent directory or not.
in the parent directory i have only directories and there are no files.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, what were the results, and how did they differ from your expectations?  (And did you try running `man test` and reading the documentation?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
path=<Path of the parent directory>
name=<Name of the directory>

if [ -d "$path/$name" ]
then
   echo "$path/$name exists"
fi
```

Comment: +1. I think you should just remove your first answer and remove the space between `path=` and `<Path of ...>` to make it not possibly misleading.